# Why don't we delete technically incorrect answers?

Tags: discussion, flagging

Should I flag an answer that is incorrect (in the hope that it will get deleted)?

For example, a post that has tried to answer the question, but the poster is clearly wrong and giving bad, or technically inaccurate, advice.

Answer (score 4):

No, is the short answer.

It should not be flagged. It should be downvoted and a comment left explaining why it is incorrect.

---

This clearly leads to the question:

> Why don't we delete bad answers?

There is a reason why the standard flag rejection message exists:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

And what is that reason, I hear you ask...

Well, there's a school of thought that says if one person thinking of something - be that an answer, question, idea, belief or assumption - then odds on, there is at least one other person thinking the *exact* same thing - be is a correct or incorrect assumption...

#### TL;TR

So, if someone posts an answer that regurgitates a mis-understanding, commonly held belief, an internet myth, or what have you, *that has been **proven** to be wrong*, then that answer should most certainly **not** be deleted, but held up as an example of inaccuracy - not to vilify the poster, but rather to re-educate, and hopefully try to stop the self-perpetuating inaccurate fact/myth in its tracks. To do that a down-vote, in conjunction with a comment, can help to do that.

Note that a downvote alone, without at least one comment, will not - as the poster probably won't understand why they are getting downvoted and just assume that it's some sort of vendetta.

---

#### Related Note

There is some confusion with *Not an answer* (NAA) and *Low quality answer* (LQA), of which a technically inaccurate answer (as described above) is neither.

This is how a I personally interpret the flags:

- NAA:

  - A comment
  - Another question
  - A "Me Too!"
  - A post that basically contains no answer whatsoever
- LQA:

  - Random letters
  - Ranting
  - Any other utter nonsense
  - Dead link
  - A post that no matter how you edit it, contains no information

This post by Shog is most useful and provides a pictorial explanation, [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer):

> [image: Apples and answers]

---

My reasoning above is derived from a mixture of feedback that I have had from declined flags that I have raised over the years on Arduino, Raspberry Pi and Electrical Engineering.